# PHP 7.3 float numbers incorrect behavior after calculation

Tags: floating-point, php-7

The following has an inexplicable behavior to me in PHP 7.3.15:

When calculating `0.012714 * 100` the PHP value is `1.2714`, but doing a comparison and `json_encode`ing the value shows that the true value is different.

Here the most simple example

```
<?php
var_dump((0.012714 * 100) === 1.2714); # false WHY? Because the real value is 1.2713999999999999
echo json_encode([(0.012714 * 100)]); # results in [1.2713999999999999]
```

I really don't understand what is going on, this used to work flawlessly in PHP 7.0.

I have read about json_encode and float numbers, but this is not that case since the comparison also fails.

The strange thing is that this works perfectly with the exact same code but the numbers reduced by a 10th.

```
<?php
var_dump((0.12714 * 10) === 1.2714); # true 
echo json_encode([(0.12714 * 10)]); # results in [1.2714]
```

How to get the old behavior back?

Comment: I suspect the true encoded values are likely [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) and not the decimal ones you think.  Due to conversion of decimal text to the encoded value, rounding occurs.  Rounding also occurs due to `*`, `/`, etc. and conversion back to decimal text.   End result - values are _sometimes_ not exactly what you think they are - just near.  Perhaps the important thing is that code should not need `0.012714 * 100 === 1.2714`, but just close.

Comment: I cannot speak to PHP, but it many languages using IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, `0.012714 * 100` yields 1.271399999999999863575794734060764312744140625, and `12.714` yields 12.7140000000000004121147867408581078052520751953125. You should expect floating-point operations, including conversions to and from decimal, to have rounding errors.

Comment: I don't understand the difference in calculating 0.12714 * 10 and 0.012714 * 100 and why this would work in PHP 7.0 and not work in PHP 7.3 anymore. The most important point is how to get the old behavior back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be connected to this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75800), one easily applicable solution to re-create the behavior before `PHP 7.1` is to simply set the `serialize_precision` value to `14`.

```
<?php
ini_set('serialize_precision', 14);
```